# In C#, how can I create a queue of processes with a common dependency which should not be used concurrently?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency, queue, race-condition

This question is a bit academic, inspired by a misunderstanding of how an API actually works, but I'm curious how I'd be able to resolve the issue in a good way if I had understood the API correctly.

Let's say we need to integrate with a service with an OAuth-like method of authenticating.  You call one server to get a token.  You then use this token to request data from other endpoints.  Here is the kicker: Each token can only be used once and will be cached by the remote server until it either expires or is consumed.  If you request a token again and there is a cached token, you will receive the same token.

Now, let's say you have multiple processes which may happen concurrently which need to integrate with this service.  They each request a token for using with the other endpoints.  It won't matter if you've cached this token or not, they will all get the same token.  Now you have a race condition where only one process will succeed and the others will fail since the token is only good for one time use.

A naïve solution would be for each process until it succeeds, but this would be inefficient and in a worse case scenario, an "unlucky" process might take forever because it always loses the race.

I'm thinking a more efficient process would submit some function to a service which would be responsible for requesting the token, handling each request in some sort of queue, and then passing it back to the consumer which might then `await` this response.

The I can imagine the function might look something like:

```
    public async Task<T> DoWithToken<T>(Func<Token, T> doSomething)
    {
        TryAsync<Token> tokenAttempt = _authorizationClient.TryAuthorize();
        T? result = default;
        _ = await tokenAttempt.Match(

            Succ: token =>
                result = doSomething(token),

            Fail: exception =>
                Console.Write($"Something went wrong: {exception.Message}")).ConfigureAwait(false);
        
        return result!;
    }
```

... but this would not control against concurrent processes also trying to use the token at the same time.

How could I do that?

Comment: _It won't matter if you've cached this token or not, they will all get the same token_ I don't really understand that part, two _different_ services will receive two different tokens, no?

Comment: In this hypothetical scenario, if the same integration user requests tokens, he/she/it will get exactly the same token until either the token is consumed or expires 12 hours later.

Comment: Is it acceptable to serialize all requests to the service? Where only one request could be in flight at any moment?

Comment: "Each token can only be used once and will be cached by the remote server until it either expires or is consumed. If you request a token again and there is a cached token, you will receive the same token." Is this something you can change? This sounds badly designed. Caching the token is incompatible with expecting each request to use a different token.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, Yes, but the question is how the consumer could control that?

Comment: @ScottHannen, as I mentioned, this question was inspired by a misunderstanding of an API.  The actual API does not work this way, but I'm curious how to solve the problem if it did.  (In actuality, the token is cached to remain valid, but each request from the server gets a different token, so there can be any number of valid tokens in flight.)

Comment: Using a `SemaphoreSlim(1, 1)` to `WaitAsync` before each request?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, I'm not familiar with `SemaphorSlim` or `WaitAsync` though it sounds promising.  Feel free to elaborate as an answer.  :-)

Comment: It would be a pretty trivial answer. :-) Maybe mark this question as a duplicate of something similar like this? [Need to understand the usage of SemaphoreSlim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056727/need-to-understand-the-usage-of-semaphoreslim)

Comment: 1. I don't see how SemaphoreSlim would send the responses back to all the methods which might consume the above, or how to make an overall solution which would use it.  2. My idea of what a duplicate is seems wildly different from what seems to pass for a duplicate around here.  A lion is not a duplicate of a tabby just because they both involve cats.

Comment: A `SemaphoreSlim(1, 1)` is like a `lock` but asynchronous. Each request will have to wait for its turn to acquire the semaphore, so all requests will be serialized. After acquiring the semaphore each request will request a token from the service, then consume it, and finally will `Release` the semaphore. That's my suggestion. Essentially you wrap your existing code in an `await s.WaitAsync(); try { /*...*/ } finally { s.Release(); }` block.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, I'm not overly familiar with lock.  This seems like a solution which would require the ability to trust the consumer to use the lock rather than a solution which would enforce the lock.

Comment: *"let's say you have multiple processes"* <== I missed this point. The `SemaphoreSlim` is a single-process solution. To synchronize multiple processes you need a [named](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/semaphore-and-semaphoreslim#named-semaphores) `Semaphore` or `Mutex`, and both of those are synchronous (they don't offer asynchronous APIs). So at least one thread per process will have to be blocked when there is contention for the service.

Comment: Related: [Async friendly, Cross-Process Read/Write lock - .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69354109/async-friendly-cross-process-read-write-lock-net)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, yes, I expect the solution would need to be blocking.  This seems helpful, though I still don't see how it all comes together...